# how to customize CameraView for android ZBar QrCode Reader

Tags: java, android, zbar-sdk, zbar

I am using Zbar for reading QRCode. I use this https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner example for my activity. 
The Question is how can I show cameraView on my FrameLayout ?

EDIT:

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    if(!isCameraAvailable())
    {
        cancelRequest();
        return;
    }

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler();

    setupScanner();

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);
    //setContentView(mPreview);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? You can place a `SurfaceView` inside. I believe there are `some` tutorials on the web.

Comment: @gunar - can you give me a link

Comment: Reading this again, why do you need to show the camera yourself? You're supposed to call a zbar specific activity and provide camera permissions. Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494034/zbar-integration-into-android-app

Comment: I can decode QR Code. But I want to customize cameraPreview. For Example: I want to show button, imageView on cameraPreview.

Comment: I have main.xml. I build some button, imageView and FrameLayout. I only want to show camera in this FrameLayout.

Comment: Then you only need to add the `CameraPreview` View in that FrameLayout. You don't need to handle the camera preview.

Comment: I would rather have a big `RelativeLayout` with CameraPreview inside (match_parent on both v/h) and add the button and imageView after that.

Comment: I think I haven't explained good. I have this https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner example. and I have main.xml file. In this Zbar example, I want to show the cameraPreview on my FrameLayout with another items(button, imageView, ...). How can I do this? I think I have to build SurfaceView for this issue. But I dont know how. Can you write code sample?

Comment: You have a `CameraPreview` class that manages the camera preview. Look in ZBarScannerActivity how that's used (created on the fly). Instead of calling `setContentView(mPreview)` you could create a viewgroup layout that adds this `CameraPreview` object and others: your label and image. Does it make sense?

Comment: That means you will have to modify the project yourself ... or import those 2 classes to your project as the license is permissive (MIT).

Comment: on scanner activity I add setContentView(R.layout.main); and FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview); but it s noteworking

Comment: how related is your `scanner activity` to `ZBarScannerActivity`? Is it the same or does it start the `ZBarScannerActivity`?

Comment: I have only that changes on ZBarScannerActivity: EDIT:

Comment: I can't figure out where you are putting this code, some context please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all remove the line that seems to me to acquire camera access: `mCamera = getCameraInstance();`. You don't want to do that as the `CameraPreview` will do it for you.

I wouldn't use a FrameLayout as items are put one after the other and you want to put your cameraPreview at last. So you should have a `LinearLayout` in another `RelativeLayout` (I know, it's not efficient, but that's fine for now). Something like (your main.xml layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/zbar_layout_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_own_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_own_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, you would need to put the CameraPreview in `zbar_layout_area`. For this reason, try to change the code to (blind coding):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isCameraAvailable()) {
        // Cancel request if there is no rear-facing camera.
        cancelRequest();
        return;
    }

    // Hide the window title.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler();

    // Create and configure the ImageScanner;
    setupScanner();

    // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
    // and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);
    LinearLayout zbarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zbar_layout_area);
    mPreview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    zbarLayout.addView(mPreview);
}
```

Also make sure you have set enough prermissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Which LayoutParams should I use? I tried 3 class but evertytime the program has stopped.

Comment: What error details are you getting? LinearLayout.LayoutParams should do if you're adding the view to a LinearLayout.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, zbar has stopped:
ERROR LIST:
performLauchActivity
hadnleLauchActivity
AndroidRuntimeException
requestWindowFeature
ZbarScannerActivity

Comment: Obviously, but what is the cause?

Comment: ERROR LIST: performLauchActivity hadnleLauchActivity AndroidRuntimeException requestWindowFeature ZbarScannerActivity. Not only one error.

Comment: Comment the `// Hide the window title.` and try again. Editing

Comment: It haven't changed anything.

Comment: thanks for the idea.
from my code sample commented first line or 2 lines. and use FrameLayout. this is the solution.

Comment: @gunar , grate answer