# Zbar android change to portrait mode

Tags: android, zbar

Im using Zbar on my project in Android Studio, i have 2 questions :

1.How can i set Zbar library to work correctly in portrait mode.

2.How can i set scan area(camera preview )not in fullscreen, and  add a button .

I have read this manual: [how to customize CameraView for android ZBar QrCode Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079439/how-to-customize-cameraview-for-android-zbar-qrcode-reader) , and add code in **ZBarScannerActivity** :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!isCameraAvailable()) {
        // Cancel request if there is no rear-facing camera.
        cancelRequest();
        return;
    }

    // Hide the window title.
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler();

    // Create and configure the ImageScanner;
    setupScanner();

    // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
    // and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);
    LinearLayout zbarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zbar_layout_area);
    mPreview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(mPreview);
}
```

but it dont work.