# Android : Easy way to implement standalone QR code scanner

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on a Android project where I need to encode and decode text values using QR code. I managed to code for encoding. I used ZXing to generate QR code for given texts. Now I need a easy step by step guidance to code QR scanner which work without installing additional applications.

Comment: I am using Zbar. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14494129/1051783) or [this](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android) for detailed info.

Comment: this has been asked several times. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854442/embed-zxing-library-without-using-barcode-scanner-app) Please use the search box.