# Installing ZBar SDK Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, zbar, zbar-sdk

I am trying to install [ZBar Android SDK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/) in Android Studio. My min supported API version is 22. I have tried methods in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556114/android-studio-0-2-6-and-zbar-project-setup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494034/zbar-integration-into-android-app) question. Both methods resulted in various different errors when calling `new ImageScanner()`. I kind of just hacked it together because there's no guide on how to install it in Android Studio.

This is my directory structure:

```
app/jniLibs/armeabi

app/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a

app/jniLibs/x86

app/libs/zbar.jar
```

I get the following error when I run `ImageScanner scanner = new ImageScanner()`

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.example.aramesh.zbartestapp-1/lib/arm/libzbarjni.so: has text relocations
```

Comment: It was updated in 2012, before Android Studio was really common, so what makes you think it will work?

Comment: @cricket_007 okay..well what is the alternative then?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Barcode scanning? I've had limited success with Zxing library

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah barcode scanning plus some OpenGL on top of that. Zxing had too much UI stuff I didn't need

Comment: Alright, well, please clarify how you "hacked" it together and the error messages you see. As far as I can tell, you include the JAR in `libs`, and you move the other files into a `jniLibs` folder, which Gradle picks up

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah that's exactly what I did, updated the OP with more information 
(sorry for the ambiguity)

Comment: Since it is looking at `lib/arm`, that is dependent upon the CPU of the device.